# Connect External Android Device to Visual Studio 2022

Tags: android, visual-studio, installation, usb-debugging

This is not a Question but a short manual on how to connect an external Android device to Visual Studio 2022 for USB Debugging in App development (in Dez. 2023). The original info is from this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gU7dvXH5060)

- open Visual Studio updater → inidvidual Components
- Install USB Device Connectivity
- In Visual Studio go to Tools → Android → Android SDK Manager
- open Tools Tab → Extras → Google USB Driver (install)
- Connect device to development machine, activate USB Debugging on  the device
- open project
- select Debug configuration
- From the menu where you select the device (e.g. android emulator/Windows machine/etc.) select you connected device
- start